# Correct way of freeing memory of a vector of structs

Tags: c++, memory, stdvector

What is the correct way of freeing the memory of an `std::vector` of `struct`?

Consider the following pseudo-code:

```
typedef struct
{
   unsigned int packageLen;
   unsigned char* package;
} PACKAGE;

std::vector<PACKAGE*>* packages = new std::vector<PACKAGE*>;

for (...)
{
   PACKAGE *tempPackage = new PACKAGE;
   // Set data of package
   packages->pushback(tempPackage);
}

// Function exit
if (packages)
   delete packages;
```

Would this correctly free the assigned memory?

Comment: no, use smart pointers

Comment: No, of course not. Vector correctly frees only its elements. So, the pointers themselves(=address values) get deleted, but not the objects they point to. Do not use raw pointers for ownership. Consider not using pointers at all: `std::vector<Package>`.

Comment: Why would freeing the struct memory be "correct"? There could be other pointers that still refer to it, and they shouldn't be invalidated just because you deleted one container.

Comment: Related: [`<memory>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory)

Comment: Avoid 'new' and the manual memory management it brings. Your programs will be much simpler.

Comment: you almost never want to dynamically allocate a standard container. They do mangage their memory dynamically already.

Comment: @idclev463035818 except `std::array`

Comment: @eerorika right, but still no reason to do it manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you are leaking memory. Here's a the right way<sup>TM</sup>

```cpp
struct Package
{
   // ...
};


int main() 
{
  std::vector<Package> packages; // no pointers involved

  // Can use vector::reserve at this point if you know how many
  // elements you are going to need

  for (...)
  {
     packages.push_back({ /*...*/ }); // may also add a constructor and call emplace_back
     // Use packages.back() or other elements as you need
  }

  // No need to free anything
}
```

You can, of course, improve this code to cater your specific case. For instance, if you know exactly how many elements you want to default initialize, you can just create them all in the constructor.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I choose this solution due to some project requirements and limitations. However, will definitely look into Smart Pointers for future use.

Answer (score 4):

> Would this correctly free the assigned memory?

No, you are leaking all your `PACKAGE` instances, and probably all your `char[]` instances. You shouldn't have `new` or `delete` in this kind of code *at all*.

```
struct Package
{
    std::string package;
};

std::vector<Package> packages;

for (...)
{
   Package tempPackage;
   // Set data of package
   packages.push_back(tempPackage);
}

// Function exit
```

Comment: You should probably `std::move(tempPackage)` ?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili probably, or even better an appropriate constructor and `emplace_back`

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately due to other constraints I can't use `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

> Would this correctly free the assigned memory?

It would correctly free the memory of the vector.

It would fail to correctly free the memory of the `PACKAGE` objects whose pointers were stored in the vector. Unless those pointers were copied elsewhere, this would be a memory leak.

Furthermore, `if (packages)` check is redundant.

There is hardly ever a good reason to dynamically allocate a vector. And there is hardly ever a good reason to use owning bare pointers. Try to avoid those.

Comment: Thanks for the help @eerorika. Would you mind ellaborating why the `if (package` is redundant? As far as I know deleting a non existing item will cause an error?

Comment: @0x436f72647265 deleting null pointer is safe. It won't cause any problems

Answer (score 1):

Rule of thumb: you need to have `delete` for each `new`.

In your example, you allocated the vector object using `new` and you deleted it using `delete`. That is correct. But you've also created many packages in loop and haven't deleted them. In order for C++ to do it for you, you would have to write your own allocator object for `std::vector` or, before deleting the vector, loop over it and delete it's items:

```
for (auto &ptr : packages) delete ptr;
delete packages;
packages = nullptr;
```

Also note that I am setting the packages pointer to `nullptr`. This won't happen by itself when you use `delete`. And while delete on nullptr is idempotent and safe, calling delete on already deleted pointer would cause program crash (which you are clearly aware of, given the condition at the end).

**NOTE**: As `@eerorika` stated, there is usually no reason to dynamically allocate `std::vector` and in modern C++, smart pointer are usually preferred (`std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`).

Comment: The rule of thumb is a good one. But since C++11, the better one is "don't use `new`"...

Comment: @DevSolar One would wish. But I know some big companies that use C++11/14 where nobody ever used a smart pointer and they either manage the memory by themselves or resort to garbage collection libraries. I think the OP question in good, because it is better to be prepared for these kinds of situations, instead of knowing everything about smart pointers and not being able to properly clean up without them.